# How to implement search functionality in Next13 application where i want to build a markdown blog where blogs are stored in the form of markdown

Tags: web, search, markdown, blogs, next.js13

[page.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QmLI.png)

//add a string or an array fo string to search or filter by tags but this is not working because useState only works on client side and fs is not available on client side (as far as i know based on my reasearch) how to solve this??

getPostMetaData works fine but there is a problem when i try to use a state how do i solve this poblem

[getPostMetaData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od9rq.png)